# AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, printing

Thank you for your help guys, i have got the code to look like below, it is not all mine but i have been editing it to try and do what i want, i am almost done i am just getting one error message at the final hurdle, i am getting a error message :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.text.AttributedString.<init>(AttributedString.java:127)
    at PrintText.print(PrintText.java:109)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.printPage(RasterPrinterJob.java:1973)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1461)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1277)
    at PrintText.printer(PrintText.java:98)
    at PrintText$1.run(PrintText.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

The above error comes after i have selected the document i want to print and before the printer box appear, what does this error message mean ?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrintText implements Printable {

    private static String mText;


    // Below the code will allow the user to select a file and then print out the contents of the file
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new PrintText();
    }

    public PrintText() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    }

                    //selects the file
                    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                    String filename = file.getName();
                    //System.out.println("You have selected: " + filename);  testing to see if file seleected was right
                    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

                    //Reads contents of file into terminal 
                    //FileReader fr = new FileReader("filename");
                    // FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:/Documents/" + "filename")); 

                    BufferedReader br = null;
                    try {
                        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        while ((mText = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            //Displays the contents of the file in terminal
                            System.out.println(mText);
                            list.add(mText);
                        }

                        printer();
                    } catch (IOException exp) {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            br.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                    //fr.close(); 
                }
            });
    }
    //private static final String mText = 
    //    "This is a test to see if this text will be printed "; //This works perfectly fine
    //AttributedString mStyledText = new AttributedString(mText);
    /**
     * Print a single page containing some sample text.
     */
    public void printer() {

        /* Get the representation of the current printer and 
         * the current print job.
         */
        PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        /* Build a book containing pairs of page painters (Printables)
         * and PageFormats. This example has a single page containing
         * text.
         */
        Book book = new Book();
        book.append(this, new PageFormat());
        /* Set the object to be printed (the Book) into the PrinterJob.
         * Doing this before bringing up the print dialog allows the
         * print dialog to correctly display the page range to be printed
         * and to dissallow any print settings not appropriate for the
         * pages to be printed.
         */
        printerJob.setPageable(book);
        /* Show the print dialog to the user. This is an optional step
         * and need not be done if the application wants to perform
         * 'quiet' printing. If the user cancels the print dialog then false
         * is returned. If true is returned we go ahead and print.
         */
        boolean doPrint = printerJob.printDialog();
        if (doPrint) {
            try {
                printerJob.print();
            } catch (PrinterException exception) {
                System.err.println("Printing error: " + exception);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print a page of text.
     */
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int pageIndex) {
        AttributedString mStyledText = new AttributedString(mText);
        /* We'll assume that Jav2D is available.
         */
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        /* Move the origin from the corner of the Paper to the corner
         * of the imageable area.
         */
        g2d.translate(format.getImageableX(), format.getImageableY());
        /* Set the text color.
         */
        g2d.setPaint(Color.black);
        /* Use a LineBreakMeasurer instance to break our text into
         * lines that fit the imageable area of the page.
         */
        Point2D.Float pen = new Point2D.Float();
        AttributedCharacterIterator charIterator = mStyledText.getIterator();
        LineBreakMeasurer measurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(charIterator, g2d.getFontRenderContext());
        float wrappingWidth = (float) format.getImageableWidth();
        while (measurer.getPosition() < charIterator.getEndIndex()) {
            TextLayout layout = measurer.nextLayout(wrappingWidth);
            pen.y += layout.getAscent();
            float dx = layout.isLeftToRight() ? 0 : (wrappingWidth - layout.getAdvance());
            layout.draw(g2d, pen.x + dx, pen.y);
            pen.y += layout.getDescent() + layout.getLeading();
        }
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Comment: classes are not _called_. methods are _called_.

Comment: ok, how do i run the printer part of my code, is this a class or a method ?

Comment: If you don't understand how to call a method, how on earth did you write the rest of this?

Comment: @BrianRoach Ain't the internet grand ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I know, it was really a rhetorical question. Keep waving the flags and the planes are sure to come.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't make the `print` method static.  You need to call this after the user has made a file selection, passing in the file contents...
2. Don't create a new instance of the `PrintText` in the `print` this is not sharing the results of the file selection with the `print` method.
3. Make sure you are honoring the Thread rules of Swing
4. If you open it, you're responsible for closing it.  Make sure you are closing you streams/readers
5. You might like to check to see if the user actually selected a file, but I'll leave that up to you.

Something more along the lines of...

```
public class PrintText implements Printable {

    private static String mText;

    // Below the code will allow the user to select a file and then print out the contents of the file
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new PrintText();
    }

    public PrintText() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                //selects the file
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                String filename = file.getName();
                //System.out.println("You have selected: " + filename);  testing to see if file seleected was right
                String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

                //Reads contents of file into terminal 
                //FileReader fr = new FileReader("filename");
                // FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:/Documents/" + "filename")); 

                BufferedReader br = null;
                try {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while ((mText = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        //Displays the contents of the file in terminal
                        System.out.println(mText);
                        list.add(mText);
                    }

                    printer();
                } catch (IOException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
                //fr.close(); 
            }
        });
    }
    //private static final String mText = 
    //    "This is a test to see if this text will be printed "; //This works perfectly fine
    AttributedString mStyledText = new AttributedString(mText);

    /**
     * Print a single page containing some sample text.
     */
    public void printer() {

        /* Get the representation of the current printer and 
         * the current print job.
         */
        PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        /* Build a book containing pairs of page painters (Printables)
         * and PageFormats. This example has a single page containing
         * text.
         */
        Book book = new Book();
        book.append(this, new PageFormat());
        /* Set the object to be printed (the Book) into the PrinterJob.
         * Doing this before bringing up the print dialog allows the
         * print dialog to correctly display the page range to be printed
         * and to dissallow any print settings not appropriate for the
         * pages to be printed.
         */
        printerJob.setPageable(book);
        /* Show the print dialog to the user. This is an optional step
         * and need not be done if the application wants to perform
         * 'quiet' printing. If the user cancels the print dialog then false
         * is returned. If true is returned we go ahead and print.
         */
        boolean doPrint = printerJob.printDialog();
        if (doPrint) {
            try {
                printerJob.print();
            } catch (PrinterException exception) {
                System.err.println("Printing error: " + exception);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print a page of text.
     */
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int pageIndex) {
        /* We'll assume that Jav2D is available.
         */
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        /* Move the origin from the corner of the Paper to the corner
         * of the imageable area.
         */
        g2d.translate(format.getImageableX(), format.getImageableY());
        /* Set the text color.
         */
        g2d.setPaint(Color.black);
        /* Use a LineBreakMeasurer instance to break our text into
         * lines that fit the imageable area of the page.
         */
        Point2D.Float pen = new Point2D.Float();
        AttributedCharacterIterator charIterator = mStyledText.getIterator();
        LineBreakMeasurer measurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(charIterator, g2d.getFontRenderContext());
        float wrappingWidth = (float) format.getImageableWidth();
        while (measurer.getPosition() < charIterator.getEndIndex()) {
            TextLayout layout = measurer.nextLayout(wrappingWidth);
            pen.y += layout.getAscent();
            float dx = layout.isLeftToRight() ? 0 : (wrappingWidth - layout.getAdvance());
            layout.draw(g2d, pen.x + dx, pen.y);
            pen.y += layout.getDescent() + layout.getLeading();
        }
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i have just one last final error appear,